# Layouting an Intent from a specific application

Tags: java, android

[image]

Can I layout an Intent so I can add some details? For example, in this image from Facebook, it goes through here from Messenger. I want to customize this layout. Is it possible to do that? Thanks

Comment: `Layouting an Intent` means nothing. You can give a layout to something which has a **visible UI**, such as an Activity or a Fragment.

Comment: intent.putExtra?

Comment: What I meant is, start another application via intent and customize the layout of that?

Comment: I'd be greatly surprised (and worried), if you could.

Comment: You mean.. it is impossible?

Comment: I really hope it's not possible. And, knowing the very strict policies of Google about developing for Android, I'd conclude that it isn't possible.